# How to make a global variable specific to only that file

Tags: javascript, scope

Many of the functions are used across several files. So, I have been refactoring my JS so I can have a single function services all the different files. I 'm new to JS and reading the docs it appears that a global variable is available throughout the app.

If I create a global variable, say `Total`, this variable **name** is used in several other parts of my app. I do not want there to be a conflict between the different `Total`s ... yet, I do want to make use of a single common function, `calculateTotals()`. Given that it is a multiuser app, I need to "fence off" each instance of `Total` from the other. I don't want to have to resort to calling them all different names.

So - how do I make a "global variable" specific to a single file?

Comment: Wrap the entire contents of your file between `(function(){` and `})();` (an immediately executed anonymous function) and assign the variables and functions you want to be globally visible to the `window` object manually.

Comment: check out module pattern

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for a namespace

Answer (score 5):

You can use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which will constrain the scope of a variable to your file.

```
(function() {
  var total = 10; // only exists in this file

  console.log(total); // returns 10
})();

console.log(total); // Uncaught ReferenceError: total is not defined
```

If you're working in Node.js, you don't need to use an IIFE. The [module system automatically does this for you](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.4.0/api/globals.html#globals_global) and this isn't something you'll need to worry about.

To understand more about scopes in JavaScript refer to the [`var` docs on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)